# django - testing a django-admin command using mock

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, mocking

I have a command (let's call it `do_thing`):

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("filename", type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with open(kwargs["filename"]) as f:
            # do something with the data here
```

and I want to use [`unittest.mock.mock_open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.mock_open) to simulate reading from a file.

Based off the example shown in the link above, I currently have (in a test in `tests.py`):

```
with patch('__main__.open', mock_open(read_data="some content here")) as m:
        call_command("do_thing", "foo.txt")
```

However, when I run this, Django/Python acts as if the `mock` patch had no effect:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'foo.txt'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the module that has `Command` class is `do_thing`. so instead of `__main__` which works when you directly execute the module, use that exact module name `do_thing`

```
with patch('do_thing.open', mock_open(read_data="some content here")) as m:
    call_command("do_thing", "foo.txt", run=True)
```